# Mercurial: detect which change sets where on main branch at a particular revision

Tags: mercurial

With repos laying around waiting to be checked in, people merging branches at random time, and general mayhem, I need to figure out exactly what(which changesets) was at the tip of main branch at the time of release (label/revision). And I have to do it retroactively and automatically. 
It seems like a basic thing that should be able to be achievable with hg log, but I can't figure out how. Please help!

With @planetmaker advice, I've tried the following, and it seems to be working!

hg log -r "branch(default) and  ::HashNumber"

Comment: Can you clarify what you need about "a particular revision"? Do you know the changeset you built from, or do you only know when you built it?

Comment: I know the hash of the default branch, from which the release is made. 
It appears that 
hg log -r "branch(default) and ::<hash of release>"
does the trick!
Big thanks to @planetmaker

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem lies in the use of revsets. Checkout `hg help revset` for a complete list of what you can do with them.

If you are interested in the changeset last changeset in BRANCHNAME prior to a certain time: `hg log -r"last(date(<2012-01-01)) and branch(BRANCHNAME)"` (`hg help dates` for options how to define the date, including exact time).

Now, if you want to use this information in a script you do not want the full log output, but just the revision or hash itself. Use the template capability to format output. Thus amend the log call appropriately:

`hg log -r"last(date(<2012-01-01)) and branch(BRANCHNAME)" --template="{node|short}\n"`

in order to only get the hash. Or use `{rev}` for the numerical changeset version (which is local to that very repo only, though); see `hg help templates` for a full list of what you can output.